# Add two different value in same column of csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, transpose

I am trying to make a preprocessing python code for my project.
Currently, I am having multiple csv files.
I am trying to do the following steps to meet my desire:

1. Choose only one row named `y` from all csv and combined row wise(make 1 csv from multiple csv).
2. Transpose whole csv data.
3. Give header
4. At last add one more column at the end of columns and add "0" up to 100 rows and add "1" after 100 rows(remaining).

eg. Current csv (All CSVs contains similar data with 3 columns x, y and z)

1.csv

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001796 | 0.116487 | 0 |
| 0.003592 | 0.116487 | 0 |
| 0.005387 | 0.116487 | 0 |
| 0.007183 | 0.116487 | 0 |
| 0.008979 | 0.116487 | 0 |
| 0.010775 | 0.116486 | 0 |
| 0.012571 | 0.116486 | 0 |
| 0.014367 | 0.116486 | 0 |
| 0.016162 | 0.116486 | 0 |
| .......... | ........... | ... |

2.csv

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001796 | 0.116 | 0 |
| 0.003592 | 0.11 | 0 |
| 0.005387 | 0.1 | 0 |
| 0.007183 | 0.11 | 0 |
| 0.008979 | 0.1164 | 0 |
| 0.010775 | 0.116 | 0 |
| 0.012571 | 0.1164 | 0 |
| 0.014367 | 0.116 | 0 |
| 0.016162 | 0.1164 | 0 |
| .......... | ........... | ... |

there are many CSVs with almost similar values.

100.csv

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001796 | 0.091 | 0 |
| 0.003592 | 0.0930 | 0 |
| 0.005387 | 0.0931 | 0 |
| 0.007183 | 0.09355 | 0 |
| 0.008979 | 0.0955 | 0 |
| 0.010775 | 0.09 | 0 |
| 0.012571 | 0.092 | 0 |
| 0.014367 | 0.0933 | 0 |
| 0.016162 | 0.0932 | 0 |
| .......... | ........... | ... |

I want (After combining all csvs in one):

| y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 | y5 | y6 | y7 | y8 | y9 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.116487 | 0.116487 | 0.116487 | 0.116487 | 0.116487 | 0.116486 | 0.116486 | 0.116486 | 0.116486 | 0 |
| 0.116 | 0.11 | 0.1 | 0.11 | 0.1164 | 0.116 | 0.1164 | 0.116 | 0.1164 | 0 |
| ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | 0 |
| 0.091 | 0.0930 | 0.0931 | 0.09355 | 0.0955 | 0.09 | 0.092 | 0.0933 | 0.0932 | 1 |
| ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | 1 |
| ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | ......... | 1 |

At the last column I want to add `1` after 50 or 100 rows.

This is so far I have done:

```
from glob import glob
from natsort import natsorted
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
from csv import reader, writer 
import shutils
from glob import glob
from natsort import natsorted
files = glob('./a_csv/*.csv')
save_path = "./data"

if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.mkdir(save_path)

#combined all csv row wise with y columns and transpose
def read_2nd(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=1, usecols=[1])

big_df = pd.concat([read_2nd(fn) for fn in natsorted(files)], axis=1)
df = big_df.T  #Transpose the data

#add_header
header = []
for i in range(0, 120):
    headers = "z_" + str(i)    
    i += 1
    header.append(headers)
type_head = "type"
header += [type_head]
#print(header)
df = df.iloc[:, :120] #csv is large, I want to choose only 120 columns
print(len(df)) # output is 200

for i in range(len(df)): # I want to divide rows into 100 and 100
    if i <= 100: # for less than 100 I want to add 0
        df.insert(120, column = "type", value = "0")
    else: #for remaining I want to add 1
        df.insert(120, column = "type", value = "1")
df.to_csv('./data/final.csv', header=header, index=False) #After adding I want to save csv as final.csv
```

Before for loop it works as I want but It doesn't add new column as I want.

Before transpose, Multiple CSVs have more than 10k rows. All CSVs have same length.

After transpose I expect to have 200 rows. Since rows are transpose, len of column becomes more than 10k so I chose only upto 120 in code.

So expected csv will have 200 rows and 120 columns.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You mention "multiple CSV files", but you show only a single CSV. You say "one row named `"y"`", but `y` is a column in your example. Also, all the values of `y` seem almost identical, which makes the example confusing (or is it a meaningful feature?). Could you make a simpler reproducible example (e.g. 2 files with a small number of values each)? Also, it's easier if you give the files as copy/pastable text.

Comment: This is just an example, Multiple csv have similar data with three columns x. y and z.

Comment: There is no such thing as "just an example". Building a good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) takes some effort and is important to elicit good answers. It is also more respectful of our time when we are trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I tried to add more explanation. Does it make sense?

Comment: What are the lengths of the CSV files? If one file has 10K rows, what is the expected output?

Comment: Before transpose, Multiple CSVs have more than 10k rows. All CSVs have same length.

After transpose I expect to have 200 rows. Since rows are transpose, len of column becomes more than 10k so I chose only upto 120 in code.

So expected csv will have 200 rows and 120 columns.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I already solved the problem and I got another solution from @Pierre,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: make a reproducible example.

```py
files = [f'/tmp/foo_{i:03d}.csv' for i in range(300)]
for filename in files:
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.uniform(size=(200, 3)),
        columns=list('xyz')
    ).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

**Step 2**: Solution

```py
# read all files, select first n_values of column y and concatenate as rows
n_values = 4  # change to the number of columns desired in output
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(filename).head(n_values)[['y']].T
    for filename in files
]).reset_index(drop=True)

# change column names 0 --> y1, 1 --> y2, etc.
df.columns = [f'y{c+1}' for c in df.columns]

# add a column 'type' with value 0 for first 100 rows, then 1 for next 100, etc.
df['type'] = df.index // 100

# result
>>> df
           y1        y2        y3        y4  type
0    0.526375  0.984637  0.684822  0.621827     0
1    0.483059  0.451609  0.466958  0.810819     0
2    0.459988  0.215904  0.925931  0.520551     0
3    0.559822  0.847502  0.382065  0.371135     0
4    0.465607  0.621670  0.670426  0.266533     0
..        ...       ...       ...       ...   ...
295  0.865073  0.472095  0.579716  0.499318     2
296  0.202211  0.440066  0.546456  0.218273     2
297  0.265703  0.416152  0.847737  0.342023     2
298  0.569874  0.634658  0.774765  0.521240     2
299  0.010179  0.148335  0.917785  0.927565     2
```

If instead, the column `type` should be 0 for the first 100 rows, then 1 ever after:

```py
df['type'] = (df.index >= 100).astype(int)
```

Comment: yes, change `n_values` to however many columns you'd like in the output.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for the effort.

Comment: Pierre I have a question, It seems that np.random.uniform generates randomness in csv columns. Is it possible to use sorting methods so that that order of csv columns stays same in new csv. I mean first csv y in first row, second csv y in second row and so on  while making final output(in df).. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just used `np.random.uniform` to create an example. The values are pseudo-random, but the order in the output is fixed: 1st value of 1st CSV will be in first row, `y1`, 2nd value of 1st CSV in 1st row, `y2`, etc. If you find that the columns are reordered lexicographically, e.g. `y1`, `y10`, `y11`, ..., `y1`, ..., then use `'f{c+1:03d}'` (or `...04d` if more than 99 columns), when renaming the columns.